# h2o python balance classes

Tags: python, machine-learning, h2o

I'm having problems implementing a simple balancing for an H2ORandomForestEstimator, I'm trying to reproduce a simple example found in Darren Cook's book written in R ('Practical Machine Learning with H2O - pag. 107).

Working on the Iris Dataset, firstly I artificially unbalance the target variable cutting out a good share of virginica keeping first 120 rows.

Then I build 3 models, a vanilla one, one where I set balance_classes as True, and a last one where I set balance_classes as True and I input a list for class_sampling_factors to oversample the virginica one. List is [1.0,1.0,2.5], referred to columns sorted alphabetically.

I train them, and then output confusion matrix for train for each one.

I'm expecting an unbalanced output for the first one, and a balanced one for the last two, while I have always the same result. I checked [the documentation example in Python](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/class_sampling_factors.html), and I can't see anything wrong (I may be tired as well).

This is my code:

```
data_unb = data[1:120,:]  # messing up with target variable
train, valid = data_unb.split_frame([0.8], seed=12345)

m1 = h2o.estimators.random_forest.H2ORandomForestEstimator(seed=12345)
m2 = h2o.estimators.random_forest.H2ORandomForestEstimator(balance_classes=True, seed=12345)
m3 = h2o.estimators.random_forest.H2ORandomForestEstimator(balance_classes=True, class_sampling_factors=[1.0,1.0,2.5], seed=12345)

m1.train(x=list(range(4)),y=4,training_frame=train,validation_frame=valid,model_id='RF_defaults')
m2.train(x=list(range(4)),y=4,training_frame=train,validation_frame=valid,model_id='RF_balanced')
m3.train(x=list(range(4)),y=4,training_frame=train,validation_frame=valid,model_id='RF_class_sampling',)

m1.confusion_matrix(train)
m2.confusion_matrix(train)
m3.confusion_matrix(train)
```

This is my output:

[my confusion matrices (wrong)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGal3.png)

this is my expected output.

[expected confusion matrices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiyPj.png)

What am I evidently missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You're not missing anything.  The `offset_column` is available in H2O Random Forest, but it's not actually functional.  The bug is documented [here](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-5341) and should be fixed in the next stable release of H2O.  Sorry about the confusion!

It should work for the rest of the H2O algos (except XGBoost).  If you wanted to try on a GBM, for example, you'd see it working.

Comment: Does the bug just affect Python? Or was this a bug introduced on the Java side, at some point? (The example in the book was done in R, and was done with H2O 3.10, IIRC.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my issue concerned the Rate column in the confusion matrices, where even for balanced models I got an unbalanced number of Iris-virginica.

Anyhow I managed to output the proper CMs, using model.model_performance(train=True), now the question is what is the difference between the matrix I get from model.confusion_matrix(train) and the one I get from .model_performance(train=True) method?

Comment: @Daniele It sounds like that is worth asking as a new question. (If you think it is part of this same one, you could edit your question and show the additional code; but that can be confusing once a question has got an answer.)

Comment: @Daniele This is a known confusion matrix bug here: https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-5243 which is probably what you're running into, but this code does not work `model.confusion_matrix(train)` so i can't replicate what you're doing.  Check out the JIRA and please add your discrepancy as a comment. Thx!

Comment: @DarrenCook It's not implemented in the backend in RF apparently... we just noticed this.

Comment: @ErinLeDell will do, thank you for the clarification!

Comment: @Daniele thanks for investigating this, the issue reported here has actually a different cause than PUBDEV-5243. I created a new jira ticket: https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-5455 - please use this one for reference (btw same issue reproduces in R as well)